# Ask for permissions after manually disabled it. (First user accept then disable in settings)

Tags: android, permissions, runtime

I need to implement checking permissions all the time. It will be easier if I wrote here example use case to show what I mean.

1) First, user install app

2) On first activity start client got dialogs with questions about grand permission

3) Client accept all permissions

4) User Manually disable permissions in app settings

5) He back to the app and now should again see dialogs with questions about grand permission

Problem is that I have problem with "5)" step. How to do that ?

P.S sorry for chaotic language

Comment: Before starting your operation, you just have to check if permission is granted and if not ask for it.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html This runs on Runtime which can dynamically see changes from user. Follow it

Comment: In my MainActivity I'm checking and requesting permissions, additionally I have "onRequestPermissionsResult" but still when I for example go to another activity and later disable manually permissions in settings and I back to this anoter activity It doesn't ask me for permissions, shoudn't it work for hole application ?

Comment: @PhátPhát I do it like that man, and still it work only for activity where all it is implemented

Comment: It will not automatically work for whole app. So you need to ask permission only when you are about to use the functionality. It doesn't make sense to ask before

Answer (score 0):

In your MainActivity which is declared in your Manifest.xml you should implement in onCreate method check for permissions and then if those are not granted ask for them.

So here is the documentation on [developer.android](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

But if you disable permissions in the meantime when you use your app, it's best to implement permission check always before the code needs it. So in case you have a method that needs storage permission you should check if that permission is granted before you execute that method.

Answer (score 0):

So You should ask for permission only when you are about to use functionality or you can implement a BaseActivity class and extend all your activities from that BaseActivity and can have your Permission request there. But ideally it should be done only when needed.

You can do it as follows -

```
if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
            return true;
        } else {

            Log.v(TAG,"Permission is revoked");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, 1);
            return false;
        }
```

And then handle it in

```
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this link for clear example of permissions. If user declined permissions in app settings also this can be handled.

https://www.androidhive.info/2016/11/android-working-marshmallow-m-runtime-permissions/

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to get this work done easily, and you are okay with using 3rd party libraries, [Here](https://github.com/hotchemi/PermissionsDispatcher) is a great library which you can use

**Brief:**

**Attach annotations**

```
@RuntimePermissions
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@NeedsPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
void showCamera() {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.sample_content_fragment, CameraPreviewFragment.newInstance())
            .addToBackStack("camera")
            .commitAllowingStateLoss();
}
}
```

A class will be generated based on your class name:
**Example:** **MainActivityPermissionDispatcher**

Initialise it in your `onCreate`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
findViewById(R.id.button_camera).setOnClickListener(v -> {
  // NOTE: delegate the permission handling to generated method
  MainActivityPermissionsDispatcher.showCameraWithCheck(this);
});
}
```

Show a custom alert every time user comes to `MainActivity` and if permission is denied or turned off via settings

```
@OnShowRationale(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
void showRationaleForCamera(final PermissionRequest request) {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setMessage(R.string.permission_camera_rationale)
        .setPositiveButton(R.string.button_allow, (dialog, button) -> request.proceed())
        .setNegativeButton(R.string.button_deny, (dialog, button) -> request.cancel())
        .show();
}
```